# MemoryError occurs when using writer.writerows(largeList) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, memory

In Python 2.7, when a large list (over 1 million floats) is written to a .csv file on Ubuntu 14.04 system with 200GB RAM, a `MemoryError` occurs.

**Code**

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([largeList])
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a1.py", line 75, in <module>
    writer.writerows([largeList])
MemoryError
```

Is there a way to write them to file without running out of memory?

Comment: Wait a minute, why do you have `[largeList]`?

Comment: Did you try `for row in largeList: writer.writerow(row)`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid An error occurs using just `largeList`, but `[largeList]` works. I think the additional `[` `]` defines the first row in the CSV?

Comment: @suzanshakya Giving that a try now...